# span's CSS doesn't work properly when I use "background-color" on container's CSS

Tags: html, css

span's CSS doesn't work properly when I use "background-color" on container's CSS. This code works, but when I uncomment the result fails. Any solution?

```
<div class="areaButtons">        
        <div class="buttonX">
            <a href="#"><span></span>Button X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.buttonX{
    height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    /* background-color: #807b7b; */ 
}
```

You can see all the code on the link https://codepen.io/aphroditef/pen/RwqQoYa

Comment: Could you describe what 'fails' means here - it looks fine to me (ie the background changes color).

Comment: I would like to keep the hover effect and the background color

When I uncomment, I have this result https://codepen.io/aphroditef/pen/MWzQJWZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of `z-index`.
Your `z-index:-1;` on `.buttonX a:before, .buttonX a:after {` put the expanding region *behind* the `background-color`

In the below snippet I've moved a few things around. Namely:

- Putting the button text in it's own `span`
- Added classes to the `span`s inside the `a` tag so we can more easily differentiate between them

```css
.buttonX {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #807b7b;
}

.buttonX a {
  width: 220px;
  height: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

.buttonX a span.text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f2dc82;
  /*background-color: transparent;*/
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-size: 26px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.buttonX a:before,
.buttonX a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f2dc82;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.buttonX a:before {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: -100px 0 0 #94864f;
}

.buttonX a:after {
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 100px 0 0 #94864f;
}

.buttonX a:hover:before {
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 #f2dc82;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.buttonX a:hover:after {
  right: 50%;
  box-shadow: -30px 0 0 #f2dc82;
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.buttonX span.other {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2dc82;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.buttonX a:hover span.other {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.buttonX a:hover span.text {
  color: #1a84f5;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="areaButtons">
    <div class="buttonX">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="other"></span>
        <span class="text">Button X<span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```